# .NET 5 vNext Resolving dependencies with parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I have been able to resolve dependencies with parameterless constructors using **vNext DI**.

But when I tried to specify a parameter for one of my dependencies, it gives runtime error:

> System.InvalidOperationException Unable to resolve service for type
>   'System.String' while attempting to activate 'Namespace.MyService'

**Constructor:**

```
public MyService(string name)
{
    // initialize
}
```

**Usage:**

```
private readonly IMyService _myService;
public Consumer(IMyService myService)
{
        // initialize
        _myService = myService;
}
```

I updated this dependency registration by adding:

```
services.AddInstance(new MyService("Hello"));
```

It only works if I update the Consumer class constructor parameter to use type **MyService**

My initial registration was:

```
services.AddTransient<IMyService, MyService>(); // Todo: configure constructor injection
```

I really want to use the interfaces not the concrete classes for this process. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's as simple as explicitly specifying the type of the service:

```
services.AddInstance<IMyService>(new MyService("Hello"));
```

The compiler would normally infer the generic parameter type, but you can always explicitly specify generic type arguments.

Answer (score 1):

another thing to consider though there is not much documentation on it yet, is instead of taking a string in your constructor take an IOptions class and put the string as a property of the options

http://shazwazza.com/post/using-aspnet5-optionsmodel/

then later if needed you can add properties to pass in without changing the constructor

Comment: I will have a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is another approach, you can add config class:

```
public class MyServiceConfig
{
    public MyServiceConfig(string name)
    {
        // initialize
    }
}

public class MyService
{
    public MyService(MyServiceConfig myServiceConfig)
    {
        // initialize
    }
}

services.AddInstance(new MyServiceConfig("Hello"));
services.AddTransient<IMyService, MyService>();
```

Comment: This answer points me what was wrong with my code. My class constructor has "string name" parameter and DI tries to inject string!